# Comprobar si existe en localStorage un un dato sin recargar la pagina

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

Intento encontrar información  sobre como leer datos almacenados en el `localStorage` sin tener que estar recargando la pagina ejemplo:

```
    if (localStorage){
      //Verificamos si soporta la caché local
    //Como Saber si existe Sidebar
    if(localStorage.getItem('Sidebar') !== undefined && localStorage.getItem('Sidebar')){
      alert("Sidebar si existe en localStorage!!");
    //Elimina Sidebar
      localStorage.removeItem('Sidebar');
    }
}
```

De esta manera logro verificar y eliminar los datos . Lógicamente esta manera solo se ejecuta cuando se carga la pagina .

Lo que necesito es una forma de que esa verificación se repite asta obtener el dato algo así como un bucle .
Aclaro los datos a verificar se originan en otra pagina de esta manera:

```
localStorage.setItem('Sidebar');
```

Luego de cumplir con una acción .

Bueno resumiendo es que necesito una manera de monitoriar la pagina asta que arroje el dato.

Espero su opiniones y sus respuestas muchas gracias .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes [suscribirte a los cambios en el almacenamiento local](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event) de la siguiente forma:

```
if (window.localStorage) {
  window.addEventListener('storage', event => {
    if (event.storageArea === localStorage) {
      if (window.localStorage.getItem('Sidebar') !== undefined
        && window.localStorage.getItem('Sidebar')
      ) {
        alert("Sidebar si existe en localStorage!!");
      //Elimina Sidebar
        localStorage.removeItem('Sidebar');
      }
    }
  }, false);
}
```

El problema que tiene este método es que está atento a cambios realizados en otras páginas, no en la actual:

> The `storage` event of the `Window` interface fires when a storage area (`localStorage` or `sessionStorage`) has been modified **in the context of another document**.

En castellano:

> El evento `storage` de la interfaz `Window` se dispara cuando un área de almacenamiento (`localStorage` o `sessionStorage`) ha sido modificado **en el contexto de otro documento**.

De manera que puedes probar a comprobar la información de manera periódica si el cambio se produce dentro del mismo documento. En ese caso te recomiendo hacerlo mediante un intervalo configurado con `setInterval()`:

```
setInterval(function() {
  if (window.localStorage) {
    if (window.localStorage.getItem('Sidebar') !== undefined
      && window.localStorage.getItem('Sidebar')
    ) {
      alert("Sidebar si existe en localStorage!!");
    //Elimina Sidebar
      localStorage.removeItem('Sidebar');
    }
  }
}, 500);
```

Comment: muchas gracias funciona al 100% saludes